# Logistic regression using a probability as Input

Tags: regression, logistic

I am creating a model that predicts the availability of machines. Historical data is given as a percentage of time that the machine is available. (e.g. machine x was available 95% of the time)

I would thus compute a logit specification model with the dependant variable not being 0 or 1, but within the interval (0,1). Is it valid and possible to use logistic regression on this scenario?

Comment: Hi Machine, welcome! Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what exactly is your data. If your data are sample sizes $n_i$ and observed proportions of success $p_i$, then you [can use logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232979/logistic-regression-use-of-real-values-between-0-and-1as-opposed-to-two-clas/233003#233003) to model such data. On another hand, if you only have values in $(0, 1)$ that you want to model, then this kind of data is to be modeled with [beta regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29038/regression-for-an-outcome-ratio-or-fraction-between-0-and-1), a regression model for conditional distribution that is [bounded on both sides](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253744/regression-bounded-between-1-and-1/253746#253746), modeled using beta distribution [parametrized by mean and precision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316086/distribution-that-has-a-range-from-0-to-1-and-with-peak-between-them/316088#316088).