# Random number (between 0 & 1; > 5 decimal places) from binomial/beta-like distribution, with set mean (same as mode & median) and set variance

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, random-variable, beta-distribution

**Due to misunderstandings and as per request I have rollbacked this question to this previous state.
Please do not answer this question instead answer this one: [Random number (between 0 & 1; > 5 decimal places) from skewed binomial/beta-like distribution, with set mean (same as mode) and set variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/501373/305461)**

*First of all this question is very similar/the same as others linked just below. However, none of the answers I saw are correct/precise enough for a distribution with the same mean, mode and median.*

[Distribution that has a range from 0 to 1 and with peak between them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316086/distribution-that-has-a-range-from-0-to-1-and-with-peak-between-them)
&
[Beta-distribution: how to generate a peak at certain mean value with a control on variance in extrems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422993/beta-distribution-how-to-generate-a-peak-at-certain-mean-value-with-a-control-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I first tried binomial, as it didnt work out I tried the beta-distibution people suggested on the other answers.
**tl;dr: Binomial has the same mean, mode and median, but the number of decimal places are dependent on variance so I cannot choose it freely.
Beta distribution allows me to choose variance and has enough decimal places but mean, mode and median are not the same.**

### Here are the rules the random number X needs to follow:

Conditions that X itself has to fulfill:

1. X must be between 0 to 1 (including 0 and 1).
2. X must have at least 5 decimal places. (ideally unlimited, but 5 would be enough maybe even 4)

Conditions that the probability density function (pdf) from which X is drawn hast to fulfill

1. The mean is also the modus/maximum and median if possible.
2. The pdf should look like a binomial distribution.

Input that I give:

1. The mean. (which should also be the most likely number to be drawn and be the median).
2. I want to be able to change the variance freely, but relative to the mean (e.g. if mean is 0.6 variance should be 0.2 but if mean is 0.99 variance shouldnt be 0.2).

I have not managed to either get binomial distributions nor beta distributions to work. I haven't found anything else. Here is the problems with either distributions.

### **Problem with the binomial distribution:**

**I cannot set the variance independently from the number of decimal places.** E.g. if I want to have high variance I can do that by reducing the amount of events I simulate in the binomial distribution. For example only 6, however that means that I reduce my possible numbers to (0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1). If I increase the events then I get more decimal places however the pdf will be extremely narrow around the mean.

[image: Histogram with events = 5, n =100,000, mean 0.8. Good variance, but numbers dont have enough decimal places]
Histogram with events = 5, n =100,000, mean 0.8. Good variance, but numbers dont have enough decimal places. Mean (red),mode/maximum (blue), median (purple), cant be seen cause they overlap.

[image: Histogram with events = 1000, n =100,000, mean 0.8. Too little variance]
Histogram with events = 1000, n =100,000, mean 0.8. Too little variance, see x axis units.

Code for binomial distribution (in R):

```
#Binomial Distribution
n_events<-10 #e.g. 10 coinflips 
probability<-0.8 #with an 80% chance of success
numbers_drawn<-100000 #how many times you do the same experiment e.g. throw 10 coins 100000 times
distribution<-rbinom(numbers_drawn, n_events, probability)/n_events #divided by n_events to rescale numbers between 0 and 1
#print(distribution)
#events = 5, 10 numbers_drawn: 1.0 0.7 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.7 1.0
#events = 1000 , 10 numbers_drawn: 0.773 0.801 0.811 0.798 0.792 0.783 0.797 0.802 0.771 0.803

#calculate mode (no R function in base package)
dist<-round(distribution, digits = 3) #if you set really narrow pdfs you  need to round to more digits to get an accurate mode
uniqv <- unique(dist) #groups same numbers
mode<-uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(dist, uniqv)))] #which number occurs most often

hist(distribution, breaks = 40, main = paste0("Mean = ", round(mean(distribution)),", mode = ", mode,", median = ", median(distribution), ", n_events = ", n_events , ", n = ", numbers_drawn))
abline(v = c(mean(distribution), mode, median(distribution) ), col = c("red", "blue", "purple"), lwd = 2)   #plot vertical lines
print(c(mean(distribution), mode, median(distribution)))
```

### **Problem with beta distribution:**

The beta distribution allows me to keep variance the same (relatively to the Mean) but change the Mean freely. I have accomplished this by keeping beta always at a certain number and varying alpha, based on the mean (see the code). At first glance it looks right but unfortunately the mean (red) does not coincide with the mode/maximum (blue) nor median (purple).

[image: Beta distributions]
Mean (red),mode/maximum (blue), median (purple)
Now I can correctly set variance however I want, but the median and mode are higher than the mean.
Because someone on one of the linked questions a the top thought this couldnt work; I added the last plot to showcase that this works for any mean. It works because as long as alpha and beta are above 1. As alpha is always higher than the set beta there are no weird edge cases.

**Do you have any ideas on how to have a distribution like the binomial one (first pic) but with more decimal places. Is this even possible?**
Even if I can already have the same mean and mode or same mean and median it would already be great.

Code for Beta Distribution (in R):

```
   mirror<-FALSE # mirror the distribution
  #if mean > 0.5 beta should be the smaller number. else alpha should be the smaller
  #if one exchanges alpha and beta distribution is mirrored
  #it is easier to mirror it than recalculating alpha if beta is set
  mean_original<-0.8
  mean<-mean_original
  if (mean < 0.5) { 
    mirror<-TRUE 
    mean<-1-mean 
  }
  beta<-10       #if you set beta higher it will narrow the pdf; below 1.5 it might lead to unintuitive output with maximum being super close to 1 or 0
  alpha<- (-beta*mean)/(mean-1)    #calculate mean solved for alpha
  var<-(alpha*beta)/((alpha+beta)^2*(alpha+beta+1)) #standard variance calculation
  #var<-(mean^3-2*mean^2+mean)/(beta-mean+1)  #calculate var just from beta and mean
  #alpha <- ((1 - mean) / var - 1 / mean) * mean ^ 2   #calculate alpha from variance and mean
  if (mirror) {
    distribution<-stats::rbeta(1000000, beta, alpha, ncp = 0) #mirror the distribution 
  }else{
    distribution<-stats::rbeta(1000000, alpha, beta, ncp = 0) #ncp = non-centrality parameter 0 is default
  }
  #if you want the mode/maximum to be e.g. 0.8, set mean to 0.8 and add 1 each to alpha and beta, however your mean is not gonna be 0.8 anymore
  print(mean(distribution)) # check if mean is what it should be
  
  #calculate mode (most common number/maximum of the pdf)
  dist<-round(distribution, digits = 5) #if you set really narrow pdfs you  need to round to more digits to get an accurate mode
  uniqv <- unique(dist) #groups same numbers
  mode<-uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(dist, uniqv)))] #which number occurs most often
  print(mode)
  cutoff<-0 #allows you to cuttoff for plotting purposes (to "zoom in" to a specific area) 
  hist(subset(distribution, distribution > cutoff),breaks = seq(cutoff,1,0.005), main = paste("Mean =", mean_original, ", n = 1,000,000, Beta & Alpha =", beta, "&", round(alpha)), xlab = "")
  abline(v = c(mean(distribution), mode, median(distribution) ), col = c("red", "blue", "purple"), lwd = 2)   #plot vertical lines
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it means for a PDF to "look like a Binomial distribution," *which does not have a pdf*?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I am not very familiar with these terms, I might have misused it. I thought what I had plotted were PDFs, but plotted from the random numbers I drew.

Comment: Why do you want this? Is this self-study for a course? If so, it needs a `self study` tag. Beta distributions can be made symmetric with a peak. Then one can transform the beta distribution to have a smaller or larger range than 0,1.

Comment: Most binomial distributions do not have mean, median and mode equal. It would also be unusual for a skew distribution with a continuous CDF to have mean, median and mode equal, especially if you want the density to be continuous too (especially if you want the density smooth at the mode).  But it could be possible if you defined the density carefully in two pieces.

Comment: @Carl I am writing a biological model for my master thesis and need that kind of distribution.

Comment: @Henry Can you explain what kind of binomial distributions do not have mean, median and mode equal. All the ones I plotted had that property.
Do you mean something like having a mean at 0.8 then, only taking numbers like 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 for the left while for the right I have smaller steps like 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1 . Thus I could have exactly the shape I want and ensure same median mode and mean.

Comment: @Henry is correct. Most binomials do not have this property and you have to look quite hard to find exceptions! Your last example is not a binomial, so not relevant to this question.

Comment: @NickCox Maybe I have not been clear enough. I do not need a binomial distribution, I just need something that looks like it that will fulfill all the rules i have specified. Same as I do not need the mode meaa an median to be exactly the same up to the last decimal place. For example I I rerun the Binomial Distribution that you gave as an example but increase events to 100. Mean, Mode and Median are the following: 0.049969 0.050000 0.050000. Of course if the events are very low and/or the mean is very close to 0 or 1 you would get examples where they are not the same.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the question and replaced PDF with distribution to avoid confusion for the reader. Sorry for having caused that confusion.

Comment: Understood, but I fear that the thread is not likely to converge satisfactorily for you. Also, comments above and my answer now show that statements in your question  about the binomial are incorrect. I will edit your question for minor style points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117293/discussion-between-alex-and-nick-cox).

Comment: I edited references to mode/maximum to mode alone as it seems clear that you do not mean the maximum when you say the mode. If that's wrong, you should revert. Otherwise, many references to "number of decimal places" suggest that you are fuzzy about the difference between discrete and continuous variables. I gather that you want a specification of a continuous distribution, and if so the binomial is out of order on principle and there is no need to discuss it at all.

Comment: Your experiments with beta distributions would be facilitated by reparametrizing them by mean and standard deviation!

Comment: Sure go ahead, I think I have understood the difference between concrete and continous variables, I wanted to showcase that the binomial distribution has exactly what I want apart from enough decimal places, basically if you imagine connecting each bar from the histogram, that is what I would like it too look like. That is why mentioned the binomial. I even stated in the question that the binomial doesnt work for what I want, and that I cant use it. I wanted to know if there is a workaround.
I am sorry if that wasnt clear enough in my question.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What do you mean by facilitate? I tried with mean and variance first but that wasn't useful as alpha and beta could become less than 1 and then it would have 2 maxima.

Comment: As said, the difference is between _discrete_ and continuous. "number of decimal places" is not a good synonym for, or alternative to,  "number of distinct values" if that is what you mean. Perhaps sone biological context  here would help make your question clearer, as I can't sense that anybody else now understands it well.

Comment: @Alex: I mean that you were varying only one of alpha and beta at a time, looking at mean/variance is more meaningful, as we have more intuition as to mean and variance. That you got bimodal distributions must be because you choose to high variance ... , so just lower it.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen First of all: I know that neither the binomial nor the beta distribution is going to work. That is why I am searching for a workaround that is **like** a binomial/beta distribution. 
Regarding your comment:
Yes, but I do not previously know what the mean is going to be. So instead of trying to predict of how to adjust the variance in order for it to not be to high, it is much easier to set either beta/alpha to e.g. 2  then calculate alpha with the mean and beta/alpha. That way it will always have the same variance relative to how close the mean is to either 0 and 1.

Comment: @Alex: If beta distribution is not flexible enough, I could try an answer using some generalizations. Or maybe you could get some help from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I had a look and tried to use the package (dropbox link is dead, here's one that works: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287608666_momentify_R_package). However, I couldnt find any instructions to use the package and I do not understand the math behind it. I am not sure what you mean by generalizations, but yes the beta distribution is not flexible enough for me.

Comment: You asked for examples of binomial distributions where the mean, mode and median differ.  You could start with most cases where $np$ is not an integer (perhaps also not half an integer) so the mean cannot match the median or mode.  For example if $n=12$ and $p=\frac17$ then the mean is about  $1.714$, the median is $2$ and the mode is $1$

Comment: @Henry Thanks, could you maybe reclarify what you meant with this:
"But it could be possible if you defined the density carefully in two pieces."
Do you mean something like having a mean at 0.8 then, only taking numbers like 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 for the left while for the right I have smaller steps like 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1 . Thus I could have exactly the shape I want and ensure same median mode and mean.
Just to clarify this is a simplified example, as I would need at least 5 decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are asking for a scaled version of a Beta variable:

- For the median to equal the mode, the two Beta parameters must be equal.
- For the distribution to be symmetric, the two Beta parameters must be equal.
- For it to have just one central mode, the common Beta parameter must exceed $1.$
- For its values to be supported in the interval $[0,1],$ the scale factor cannot exceed one-half the smallest of $\mu$ and $1-\mu.$  Let the actual scale factor be $f$ times this limiting value, with $0\lt f \le 1.$

For a given target mean/mode $\mu$ and relative scale factor $f$ set $s(\mu, f) = f\min(\mu,1-\mu).$  Then for a variance of $v$ the Beta parameter must exceed

$$\alpha(\mu,\sigma,f) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{s(\mu, f)^2}{v}-1\right).$$

Shift and scale this Beta variable to place its mean (which is $1/2$) at $\mu$ and to give it the desired variance.  Here is an `R` implementation to generate $n$ independent draws from this distribution:

```
rf <- function(n, mu, v, f=1) {
  if (isTRUE(mu <= 0 | mu >= 1)) stop("Invalid mean.")
  if (isTRUE(f > 1)) stop("Invalid scale factor.")
  s <- min(mu, 1-mu) * f
  alpha <- (s^2/v - 1)/2 
  if (isTRUE(alpha <= 0)) stop("Variance too large.")
  ((2*s) * rbeta(n, alpha, alpha) - s) + mu
}
```

Its values are double-precision floats, giving over 15 decimal digits of precision.

The figure shows histograms of one million draws (each) from five such distributions.  Following it is the `R` code showing how `rf` was used to create the figure.

[image: Figure]

Notice how, in the left examples (with the same mean and variance), scaling the distribution down forces the Beta parameter to be smaller, changing the distributional shape.  I introduced the parameter $f$ expressly to create this flexibility.

```
parameters <- list(
  c(mu=0.5, v=1/50, f=1),
  c(mu=0.5, v=1/50, f=1/2),
  c(mu=0.8, v=0.004, f=1),
  c(mu=0.1, v=0.001, f=3/4),
  c(mu=1/3, v=0.005, f=1)
)
n <- 1e6
par(mfrow=c(1, length(parameters)))
for(i in seq_along(parameters)) {
  p <- parameters[[i]]
  x <- rf(n, p["mu"], p["v"], p["f"])
  mu.s <- sprintf("%.2g", p["mu"])
  v.s <- sprintf("%.2g", p["v"])
  f.s <- sprintf("%.2g", p["f"])
  hist(x, freq=FALSE, breaks=50, xlim=0:1, 
       border="#00000040", lwd=0.1, col=hsv(i/length(parameters), .65, 1),
       main=bquote(paste(mu==.(mu.s), ", ", sigma^2 == .(v.s), ", and ", f == .(f.s))))
  abline(v = mean(x))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, unfortunately I am not sure this is what I need. If for example the mean is 0.9 then I would like it to be possible for a 0.7 to be drawn although somewhat unlikely. I added a picture to the question.

Comment: Could you maybe write an Edit in your answer specifying that this is not what I asked for so that people don't assume that the question has been answered already?

Comment: You changed the question.  Thus, the onus is on you to make that clear in the question itself.

Comment: The question was already clear, I stated that I wanted it to look like a binomial/beta distribution and linked two questions which asked for nearly the same thing, thus it should have been clear that I was not looking after a symmetrical distribution. After your answer I respecified with a picture to make sure it could not be misunderstood in any way. If you leave your answer up like this it looks like the question was answered, which does not help anyone that is googling for this and looks at your answer. However, I think it can still be useful if you specify what it does answer at the start.

Comment: Since you are moderator maybe you can advise me:
Someone (I assume you) unupovoted my question at 13:25 exactly the time of your comment and 3 further people downvoted my question within half an hour, and  3 people upvoted your comment. Thus, it seems that the community likes your answer but not my question, and sees me at fault for having reclarified my question so I am wondering, if I should edit my question to fit your answer and then simply ask my question again? That way it would help people since the question and corresponding answer are at the same place.

Comment: This is a tough situation. Usually we use comments to try to clarify questions before answering. In this case I asked for clarification, thought I had it, and ventured an answer, only to have the question change in an important way.  It is probably best, then, to revert the question to the one that was originally answered and, as you suggest, post a new question.  In the new question you may link to this one to help readers understand its history and to appreciate how it differs from the original.

Comment: I do not understand how you can keep saying that I changed the question when your answer not being related to my question stems from a misunderstanding in the comments. 
But I do not want to spend anymore time on this, I will do as you say, if you think your answer answers my question in its original state so be it.

Comment: I'd advise never saying that your question is clear. I sense your strong frustration here: you put a lot of work into formulating your question and naturally hope that it is as clear as you can make it. Nevertheless, whether your question is clear to anybody else to answer it is the key, and you can't say that on behalf of other people.  Adding lengthy detail can also backfire mightily just as much as asking a brief question that appears cryptic, as people can just back off, despairing of grasping everything you're saying and lacking the time and incentive to study a long question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reply to a question asked by the OP in comments [edited for grammar]:

> Can you explain what kind of binomial distributions does not have
> mean, median and mode equal? All the ones I plotted had that property.

This won't go easily as a comment. It's an example of a binomial in which the mean, median and mode do not all coincide. The table shows probabilities for (0, ..., 10) successes out of 10 if probability of success is 0.05. The median and mode are both 0 but the mean isn't. The syntax is Stata syntax but the calculation is, or should be, standard in any good software. There are many other such examples.

Another way to see this is that the median and mode must be an integer or conventionally a half-integer if adjacent values have equal frequencies, but there is no such rule for the mean.

```
. mata : (0::10), binomialp(10, (0::10), 0.05)
                  1             2
     +-----------------------------+
   1 |            0   .5987369392  |
   2 |            1   .3151247049  |
   3 |            2   .0746347985  |
   4 |            3   .0104750594  |
   5 |            4   .0009648081  |
   6 |            5   .0000609352  |
   7 |            6   2.67260e-06  |
   8 |            7   8.03789e-08  |
   9 |            8   1.58643e-09  |
  10 |            9   1.85547e-11  |
  11 |           10   9.76563e-14  |
     +-----------------------------+
```