# calculate standard deviation and generate N random number between 2 numbers

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, python

I want to generate a random normal distribution between 0 and 1 recursively. I can generate them if I know the mean, standard deviation (taking an approximation) and size by using something like np.random.normal(size=600, loc=0.5, scale=0.153). The catch is I have to be careful while giving the standard deviation so that the distribution remains between 0 and 1. But is there any way I could generate them if I only know the size and the mean. My input is only the size N, mean = 0.5 and starting and end points i.e 0 and 1 between which I want to generate the numbers. Could someone please help? What I have done so far is as below:

```
rng_seed = np.random.default_rng(12345)
for i in range(2):
    a = rng_seed.normal(0.5, 0.153, 601)
    b = np.random.normal(size=600, loc=0.5, scale=0.153)
    plt.hist(a)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to lie between 0 and 1 then the normal distribution is not a good choice to generate your data. Suggestion: the beta distribution.

Comment: If a random variable $X$ follows a normal distribution, then $X$ is **not** bounded, and can take values arbitrarily close to +infinity or -infinity, albeit with very small probability.

Comment: Following @ocrams's suggestion, to get a beta distribution with mean $\frac12$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, you can use the parameters $\alpha=\beta=\frac{1}{8\sigma^2}-\frac12$ and you will get a bell shaped distribution on $[0,1]$.  But you do need the standard deviation or something equivalent to it.

Comment: You can simulate from a truncated Normal distribution, restricted to $(0,1)$, while taking care of the parameterisation of the Normal in order to fit your intended mean and variance. See, e.g., [my 1995 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4010) or the [R package truncnorm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/truncnorm.pdf).

Comment: However, if you only set the mean value, there is an infinity of truncated Normal distributions fitting the requirement, as already pointed out by @Henry.

Comment: A $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution truncated to $(0,1)$ has mean$$\mu+\frac{\phi(1)-\phi(0)}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(0)}\sigma$$and a slightly more complex [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the valuable inputs, but I don't have a fixed SD or variance. Please allow me to rephrase my question. I want to generate a bell-curved distribution between 0 and 1 where the input is size N and the mean is 0.5.

Comment: Although -- as has been pointed out in most of these comments -- your criteria do not determine a solution, when you want the mean to be $1/2$ and the SD to be $\sigma = 0.153$ (say), then a Beta$(\alpha,\alpha)$ distribution conforms to your requirements with $\alpha = (1/\sigma^2 - 4)/8.$  A general answer (arbitrary mean and SD) for Beta distributions is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500862.  Perhaps that addresses your question?